# Setting component sizes inside Jpanels with Borderlayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a project to copy the google sign-in GUI [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocmCf.jpg) . So far I'm still searching on what I'm gonna start with, but after some research I think it is possible on BorderLayout to do this. Im getting how it works by readjusting everything through borders, and I kind of like it because it is quite responsive compared to having null layout and coding every setBounds for each component.

I've been imagining using a background panel, a panel for the fill up form,
and creating panels for each pair of label and textfields to properly create the space and stacking (or nesting) them on top of the other. Our teacher just told us to snip out the image, she just wants if we know how to design something out of scratch. That and also saving the input into a text file.

However, I can't seem to grasp the concept of increasing the component size inside the borders to imitate the gaps between the text fields, like some sort of a padding between components? Using setSize doesnt work and so far my search only results into resizing borders, or perhaps I still have not entered the right searachable term for it?

Also, Ive been looking for another way and I think this project will also work using GridBaglayout. However many people say GridBagLayout is too complicated. What do you think would be easier?

Comment: Merely opinion based but I prefer `GridBagLayout`. Use its `Insets` to manage the gaps.

Comment: Hmm, I see the insets are made on one object. So if one component should not follow the already declared, does that mean I will need to create another one? For example, the Next step button seems to have a farther distance than the other paddings. That means this new inset object must adjust to the changes of the other one, or is there such thing in the API that handles this situation?

Comment: @inNeedOfHelp On a side note: check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html to get a basic visualization of the different basic layout manager. Also keep in mind that you can place panels inside other panels and each panel have a layout manager, which can be different to other panels.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience almost every (99%) of the panels using `GridBagLayout` can be designed by using all other layouts. So, someone could say that `GridBagLayout` is optional

In your situation, avoiding the use of a `GridBagLayout` is easy. Take a look at the following code:

```
public class NoGridBagLayout extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new NoGridBagLayout().setVisible(true));
    }

    public NoGridBagLayout() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        JPanel borderPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        borderPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("borderPanel - BorderLayout"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Create a google account.");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(25f));
        borderPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        setContentPane(borderPanel);

        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        gridPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("gridPanel - GridLayout"));
        getContentPane().add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel leftBoxedPanel = new JPanel(); // Fill it with panels using BoxLayout.X_AXIS
        leftBoxedPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftBoxedPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        leftBoxedPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("leftBoxedPanel - BoxLayout.Y_AXIS"));
        gridPanel.add(leftBoxedPanel);

        JPanel rightBoxedPanel = new JPanel(); // Fill it with panels using BoxLayout.X_AXIS
        rightBoxedPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightBoxedPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        rightBoxedPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("rightBoxedPanel - BoxLayout.Y_AXIS"));
        gridPanel.add(rightBoxedPanel);
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image: preview]

Comment: Wow, that is a clean one! I think I have decided to switch to the GridBagLayout to create the form itself, and make the BorderLayouts on the external placing stuff.